# Does Captain Archer ever meet any other Enterprise captains?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

We know that Kirk meets Picard in Generations. And that Scotty mentions an "Admiral Archer" in Star Trek (2009). Does Archer ever meet any other Enterprise captains?

Comment: i believe the admiral archer in startrek 2009 is "captain archer" as they mention teleporting his prized beagle.

Comment: @Himarm That was the inference I took as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends what you consider to be a "Captain" of The Enterprise.

It sounds weird, but bear with me. T'Pol and Tucker have both temporarily acted as Captains on the Enterprise. In addition to this, their son, Lorian, from an alternate timeline, was also Captain of the Enterprise until he went back in time and changed history. Captain Archer has certainly met all three of these people.

However, if you limit it simply to people that have been appointed Captain of The Enterprise, then none of the above count, in which case we have to move onto The Enterprise NCC-1701. The captains of this vessel are (in order): April, Pike, Kirk, Decker and Spock. After that we have The Enterprise-A,B&C before moving onto Picard's era. There is nothing to suggest that Archer has met any of these Captains, and while it is possible for him to have met the likes of April or maybe even Pike, it is unlikely that he will have met anyone from Kirk onwards, since Archer was 121 years old when Kirk was born.

Each of these Captains, however, will know of Jonathan Archer, being the man who made the United Federation of Planets possible, and who was President of that same Federation for 8 years.

I also believe it to be quite likely that, as an Admiral, Archer would have had some say in who was appointed Captain of The Enterprise.

So, in short, Jonathan Archer has met people that have Captained The Enterprise, but as far as canon material goes, he has not met any person that has been appointed Captain of The Enterprise by Starfleet.

Comment: In the Kelvin timeline, it seems *likely* he has met Kirk, since Scotty seems to have interacted with him at the Academy

Comment: Scotty interacted with his dog, not with him personally, and nobody said it was Archer that had him put on Delta Vega, so we don't even have solid evidence that he's met Scotty, let alone Kirk.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Uhm......archer made sure scotty was at delta vega. But else valid point there....he doesn't need to have met scotty personally to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Jonathan Archer has once visited the Enterprise-J, but it is unclear if he met its Captain while on board:

> DANIELS: You're on Enterprise. Enterprise J to be exact, a distant relative of your ship. We're four hundred years in the future.

[S3, "Azati Prime. [From Chakoteya.net](http://chakoteya.net/Enterprise/70.htm)]

Answer (score 1):

According to material seen on screen for Archer's biography (seen in "In a Mirror Darkly", using information from the "Normal" universe) he, "... died at his home in upstate New York in the year 2245, exactly one day after attending the christening ceremony of the first Federation starship Enterprise, NCC-1701"

Presumably, by that quote, Archer would've met Captain April, mentioned as the first captain of the *Enterprise*

There is, of course, the possibility that Archer met with a future Captain of the *Enterprise* (i.e. Cadet Kirk or a younger Spock) before they'd become Captain, but there is no source to support that.

Sources: Quote from on-screen text in "In a Mirror Darkly" 
April was a former Captain of the Enterprise according to TAS: The Counter-Clock Incident

 Christopher Pike was a former Captain, as mentioned in TOS: The Menagerie and TOS: The Cage

Comment: "The Counter-Clock Incident" says that April was the first captain of the NCC-1701, and also oversaw her construction. I can't imagine that he wouldn't have been at the christening ceremony, though admittedly we have no direct evidence of this.

Comment: Why wouldn't the first captain of the vessel (Robert April) be at its christening?

Comment: @Valorum Do the future captains of vessels normally attend the christening?

Comment: @matthewBarclay - The two christenings we see on screen both had their future captains in attendance

Comment: It's a good find but you'd do better to use it as evidence of April being present (probably) rather than not being present (which would be unusual). Your source doesn't back up your thesis

Answer (score 1):

He met John Harriman of the *Enterprise*-B. Harriman has at least one non-canon novel about him, at the end of which he passes command over to Sulu's daughter. Another novel has him meet Captain Morgan Bateson, not long before Bateson's ship *Bozeman* ends up in the future and nearly collides with the *Enterprise*-D. In that same novel, Bateson ends up becoming the first captain of the *Enterprise*-E, before handing over command to Picard.

Comment: Hi there! Which novels are those? Could you please [edit] that information in? :)